# How to setup checkbox on index view based on model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model `product` and it has an attribute called `active`, in the index im showing the full list of products.

So, what I want to do is to show the attribute `active` as a checkbox checked or unchecked based on the product active attribute,

I´ve been trying with `check_box_tag` but it doesnt work, it shows the checkboxes always checked, here is my code line for `checkboxes`.

I´m using smallint on db with postgres, saving just 1 or 0:

```
  <%= check_box_tag "Active", product.active, product.active,disabled: true %>
```

Comment: you probably want to define a method `active?` on `Product` in order to return either `true` or `false` based on the (int) value of `active`. You will then be able to use it anywhere in your code when you need the `true`/`false` version of `active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using bootstrap 3 you can use this idea

setup in product.rb one method like this

```
  def active_status
    if product.active
      "glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"
    else
      "glyphicon glyphicon-minus text-danger"
    end
  end
```

and in your show.html.erb you can output as follow

```
<i class='<%= product.active_status %>'></i>
```

this will showing green green check mark if product.active equal to true and minus sign if false

Answer (score 0):

The `cheack_box_tag` method in Rails can take a few different arguments. According to [APIDock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) (`check_box_tag 'eula', 'accepted', false, disabled: true`) the argument that determines if the checkbox is marked is the third argument. It looks like you're passing `product.active` into that argument. According to your question, you say it's return a 1 or a 0, which are both objects and interpreted as True in Ruby. I'd suggest a ternary statement to get around that mess.

`<%= check_box_tag "Active", product.active, (product.active == 1 ? true : false), disabled: true %>`